# RegEx with escaping and limit

Tags: regex

I have a regex now that will find words that are a mix of letters and numbers

```
(?<=|\W)(\d+[A-Z]+\w*|([A-Z]+\d+\w*))
```

for example, it will find apple6 or $6ap7le8 and ignore 12345 or applesix

I am trying to add two things together:

The first is a limit, so it only checks for words that match the above criteria if the word is 4-8 long so it will ignore ap1 or apple547474

Next I want it to ignore any words that have a \ or .

I hope my question is clear enough

Thanks everyone

edited to fix issue of missing )

Comment: the regex you posted has an error, apparently a `)` is missing. Please fix

Comment: sorry, I fixed my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this: `(?=\S*\d)(?=\S*[^\d\s])(?!.*[.\\])(?<=\s|^)\S{4,8}(?=\s|$)`

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/faZ0Dc/2/)**

**Explained:**

The basic regex is `(?<=\s|^)\S{4,8}(?=\s|$)` which matches non whitespace characters sorrounded by spaces/begin/end of lines. Then you add some constraints using lookaheads. With the first lookahead you force some digit to appear. The second does the same with non-digit characters, and the third one avoids non desired characters (`.` and `\`)